# Cant use Linq with nested class List<> on MongoDb C#

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I have the following classes:

```
public class Company
{
   [BsonId]
   public string dealerId = null;

   public List<Dealer> dealers = new List<Dealer>();
}

public class Dealer
{        
   public string dId = null;          
   public int dIndex = -1;

   public List<AutoStore> stores = new List<AutoStore>();
}

public class AutoStore
{
   public string type = null; 
   public  Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

I am able to store the `Company` class objects in Mongo with `Insert()`. The problem is when I search for a document and try to use LINQ on the `List<>` items. I constantly get an exception .

```
var query =  collection.AsQueryable<Company>()
                 .Where(cpy =>
                     cpy.dealers.Where(dlr => 
                         dlr.stores.Count == 1).Count() > 0) ;
```

Running this code I get:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the serialization
>   information for the expression: Enumerable.Count

I just started using Mongo today, but I thought the `LINQ` support was more mature. Can anyone tell me if I can do a nested array query like I've done with `C#` and`LINQ` ?

As soon as I remove the `Where()` on any of the `List<>` , that exception isn't thrown

Comment: Any reason why you use `Count` twice? Try to use `cpy.Dealers.Any(dlr => dlr.stores.Count ==1)` if all you want to do is see if the dealer has any stores (that's what I judge from the code)

Comment: In general in LINQ, instead of saying `.Count() > 0` or `.Count(lambdaFunc) > 0`, **always** use `.Any()` respectively `.Any(lambdaFunc)`. The reason is that to determine the count, it will have to iterate the entire source to the end, while to determine if there is `Any`, it only has to iterate until it finds the first element! (And `Any` is even easier to type than `Count` and `> 0`.)

Comment: And an extension of this comment. Instead of saying `.Count() == n` for some positive integer `n`, it might perform better to say `.Take(n + 1).Count() == n`. And so on.

Comment: Jodrell: collection is an object returned from database.GetCollection<> ; Jeppe Stig: Thanks for the tip, I will use Any() from now on; LukeHennerly: I tried it without using Count() but I still got an exception on Where(). I dont have to use Count, but I was just trying a simple query to test against my inserted data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going by your exception the problem area is within where you are doing `Where` statements.

As I said in my comment. Try to do:

```
var v = collection.AsQueryable<Company>().Where(cpy => cpy.Dealers.Any(dlr => dlr.Stores.Count == 1));
```

You are currently doing something like:

```
var dealers = collection.AsQueryable<Company>().Select(cpy => cpy.Dealers);
var dealersWithStores = dealers.Where(dealer => dealer.Stores.Count == 1);
```

You are then checking if there are `any` dealers with stores by calling count and checking if that is more than 0 to get your `bool` in the where. All of  this is the same as calling `IEnumerable.Any()`. See if this works? :)

Comment: LukeHennerly: Yay, that worked. You are awesome ! Any() worked. I agree that Any() is more efficient, but I guess Where() queries how I was using them with MongoDb are not supported ? Either way, I'm excited that I can do multiple nested LINQ queries within Mongo now. Thanks again Luke !

Comment: @AriesOnTheCusp I think it was more that you were calling `Count()` on the enumerable which was returning which was somehow not supported. Perhaps try `Count` as a property?

Answer (score 3):

You could write you query more efficiently as

```
var query =  collection.AsQueryable<Company>()
                 .Where(c => c.dealers.Any(d => d.stores.Count == 1);
```

If the Mongo querty provider is struggling to support `IList`, you might find

```
var query =  collection.AsQueryable<Company>()
                 .Where(c => c.dealers.Any(d => d.stores.Count() == 1);
```

works better. If so, reports of the maturity of MongoDBs query provider are exaggerated.

Comment: Thanks Jodrell, would have marked yours as the answer, but I saw Luke's response first.