# Can't use Linq with nested class List<string> on MongoDb

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

Very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622163/cant-use-linq-with-nested-class-list-on-mongodb-c-sharp) question, however the answer provided does not solve this case.

I have the following class

```
public class Company
{
   [BsonId]
   public string dealerId = null;

   public List<string> dealers = new List<string>();
}
```

I am trying to query with the following query

```
collection.AsQueryable<Company>()
          .Where(cpy =>
                 cpy.dealers.Where(dlr => 
                         dlr.ToLower.Contains("dealer1")).Any());
```

Doing this results in the following

> Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression:
>   Enumerable.Where(cpy.dealers, (String dlr) =>
>   dlr.ToLower().Contains("dealer1"))

I believe it is possible to create a wrapper around the string and use Any with a predicate however that's not a very elegant solution. Is there a simple way of doing this that I have completely missed?

I am using mongodb 2.6.4 with C# driver 1.9.2

### Edit:

I want the above linq query to be converted to either of the following native mongo queries,

```
db.Company.find({dealers: {$regex: /dealer1/, $options: "is"}})
```

or using elemMatch

```
db.Company.find({dealers: {$elemMatch: { $regex: /dealer1/, $options: "is"}}})
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: See if you can write this in native MongoDB query syntax and we'll work to figuring out how to get that rendered using Linq (which may not be possible right now).